# NuGet Fallback to .Net 3.5 Framework from Unity Target Profile

Tags: unity-game-engine, nuget

I'm developing some shared class libraries for Unity games and I would like my libraries to target the custom target framework `Unity 3.5 .net Subset Base Class Libraries`.  But when I do so, most published NuGet packages do not install.  They fail with error "the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework".

Most of the time if the dependency library I'm trying to install has a .Net 3.5 target, it will actually work fine.  There are cases where that library will not work because it uses a portion of the .Net framework that Unity's flavor of Mono does not support.  But I would really like to use NuGet to install the package anyway so I can try it without having to reference the binary directly.

I do not see any parameters to the [Install-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference#install-package) powershell command to let me specify the .Net Target.  Is there something I'm missing with NuGet to allow me to specify the .Net target of the dependency to install?

Alternatively, is there a way to configure NuGet to use its fallback mechanism to set "net35" as a fallback to "net35-unity subset v3.5" and "net35-unity full v3.5" frameworks?  Like it already does with "net20" and "net35" etc.

Comment: Just added [this suggestion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4319) to the NuGet issues page.

Comment: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20150523-UsingNuGetInVisualStudioToolsForUnity.html Not sure if this is relevant, but worth knowing anyway perhaps.